# How can I shuffle a list and keep record of the different arrangements using lists and for loops in python?

Tags: python, loops, cs50, nested-lists

I want to shuffle 3 cards using random.shuffle() in every loop and add the new arrangement into my shuffles list.

```
import random
cards =["Jack","Queen","King"]
#random.shuffle(cards)
Shuffles =[]
for i in range(4):
    random.shuffle(cards)
    Shuffles.append(cards)
print(Shuffles)
```

What I am getting instead is a nested list with the latest shuffle. Every time the order changes, somehow all list that had been added on Shuffles will update to the new arrangement.
What should I do to keep track of all the different arrangements in a nested list??[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eedBF.png)

Comment: You end up adding same object over and over again. shuffle (or append) a copy of the list

Comment: Than you so much @buran, solved.

Answer (score 0):

when you say Shuffles.append(cards), it adds the variable cards, that is the varaible you define at the begining. You should do that :

```
import random
cards =["Jack","Queen","King"]
#random.shuffle(cards)
Shuffles =[]
for i in range(4):
    new_card_arrangement = random.shuffle(cards)
    Shuffles.append(new_card_arrengement)
print(Shuffles)
```

I hope it will helps you, bye !

Comment: I tried a similar method but I'd get an error that "new_card_arrangement" is not defined.

Comment: @BrownBakani I misswrote arrangement the second time but it works i think if you corrige